# Function overloading in namespace in c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, namespaces, overloading

I need help in implementing the below task. 
So I want to have namespace's with same named classes RHS inherited from some library class Function, same named function RHSvalue inside the RHS classes with different implementation in each namespace. Also the class Function doesnt have any function named RHSvalue in its implementation.

```
namespace S50{                  // Mother namesapce in which i want to implement all tasks
 class Coeff: public Function { // Function class from some library
public:
virtual double value();
virtual void value_list();
};
}

namespace Charge{
class RHS: public Funtion {
virtual double RHSvalue (); // Function class does not have any function named RHSvalue()
};
}

namespace S16{
class RHS: public Function {
virtual double RHSvalue(); // same named function in other namespace with other implementation
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've got what you want... I mean what you described.

Some comments:

1) you don't need RHSvalue to be defined in the Function class, but if it's not then you cannot call RHSvalue funciton using a pointer to Function, eg.

```
Function* function = new Charge::RHS();
function->RHSvalue(); // ERROR
```

2) What is the Coeff class for? You haven't mentioned it in the description

3) If you need different implementations then just put something like this:

```
namespace Charge{
    class RHS: public Funtion {
    virtual double RHSvalue () { std::cout << "From Charge"<< std::endl; }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thats precisely what I want. I want to make a pointer dynamically pointing to one of the namespace object's RHS class.

Comment: for eg.  std_cxx11::shared_ptr<Function> RhsFunc = std_cxx11::make_shared<Function> (Step16::RHS()) ;